# Body content appears to anonymous viewer but not to site admin

Tags: 7

In Drupal 7, on my front page, when logged in as admin, the node's content is not rendered.

[image]

However, when I log out, I can see content

[image]

This only occurs on one content type (called Front Page). No other content type mimics this behavior.

We're using [Responsive Premium](https://drupal.org/project/responsive) as our base theme, of which it is based on omega.

Is there a permission that I have forgotten about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the field permissions in your content type. If you added custom permissions to a field and did not grant admin role access, the node will not be displayed.

By "admin" do you mean uid1 superuser or user in a role named "admin"

Comment: The user role is the second -- a user with a role "admin." In permissions, I don't directly see a view option for fields in admin/people/permissions. Suggestions. As it turns out I might just use Node Convert to move these to a fresh Content Type and delete the failing Type. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If you are using the Field Permissions module https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions I'm thinking it's possible someone added custom permissions that did not include the admin role for one of the fields. Can you see the content as superuser uid?

Comment: Another thought: have you tried rebuilding the content permissions? `http://yoursite/admin/reports/status/rebuild` or click the link at `http://yoursite/admin/reports/status`